# Will kill Salt the Yeast, salt is a hunter?

Tags: yeast

When making bun, Yeast & salt should not be mixed at the same time?
Will kill Salt the Yeast, salt is a hunter?

Comment: Are we talking about mixing the salt in when proofing the yeast, or are you dealing with 'instant yeast' which gets mixed in later with the flour?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16927/67

Comment: "Salt is a hunter" ... wonderful indie rock band name or novel title!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Salt definitely will kill yeast in direct contact. Salt is a 'control' for yeast. For instance, if you are working in a professional bakery and you need your doughs to move faster, you can cut back a bit on your salt content...

If you take fresh yeast in the palm of your hand, add a pinch of salt. Massage that salt in, and the yeast will liquefy within seconds (and will definitely be dead).

Don't mix them together!